# Calculus of variations Euler-Lagrange equation and variational problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations

> Find all the extrema (local minima and maxima) of the function $$J[y] = \int\limits_1^2(xy' + y)^2\,\mathrm dx;\qquad y(1) = 1, y(2) = \dfrac12.$$
>
> *Hint*. Once you've found the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation with the boundary conditions, remember to check, like in the previous problem, if this solution is a minimum, a maximum or not an extremum.

[image: My work.]

The image above shows my work. I'm pretty sure I solved the E-L equation correctly with the boundary conditions, but I am not too sure about the variation part. I always seem to find an absolute minimum, which makes me think my understanding of this part is lacking.

Comment: _At least_ make sure that the picture has a correct orientation. Also, it is better if you type out the problem text using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting as a picture. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-pic-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than going through your work line by line, let's see if I get the same answer: $$L=x^2y^{\prime2}+2xyy^\prime+y^2\implies 0=\frac{(\partial_{y^\prime}L)^\prime-\partial_yL}{2x^2}=y^{\prime\prime}+\frac2xy^\prime\implies y=A+\frac{B}{x}.$$The boundary conditions give $y=\frac1x$, as you said. With $y=\frac1x+\eta$ we get$$J=\int_1^2(x\eta^\prime+\eta)^2dx,$$which is minimal for $\eta=0$, so you're also right about the stationary point being a minimum.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Is the best way to find if it is min/max to just plug in y = η in to the functional then considering if it is minimal/maximal for η = 0?

Comment: @PeterPolizogopoulos You mean $y=y_0+\eta$, where $y_0$ is the solution you want to classify. It's the best approach if you're not *au fait* with second-order functional derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can change the variable $$z(x)~:=~xy(x).$$
Then OP's variational problem simplifies to
$$I[z] ~:=~ \int_1^2z^{\prime 2}\,\mathrm dx~\geq~0;\qquad z(1)~=~1~=~z(2).$$
Note that the functional $I$ is non-negative.
The [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) becomes $z^{\prime\prime}=0$. With the correct BCs, the EL equation leads to the constant solution $z_{\ast}(x)=1$. Since $I[z_{\ast}]=0$, the unique stationary solution $z_{\ast}$ minimizes the functional $I$.